# Stack: 'hdevtools is a library dependency, but the package provides no library needed since my-app is a build target.'

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I was trying to add `hdevtools` to my stack project, so I ran `stack build hdevtools`. The install seemed to work successfully, and my text editor stopped reporting imported libraries installed via stack (like aeson and tasty) as missing.

However, things went wrong when I added this line to the `dependencies` section of my `package.yaml` file:

```
- hdevtools >= 0.1 && < 1
```

And then tried to run `stack build` again. I received the following error output:

```
Error: While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:

In the dependencies for my-app-name-0.1.0.0:
    hdevtools is a library dependency, but the package provides no library
needed since my-app-name is a build target.

Some different approaches to resolving this:

  * Consider trying 'stack solver', which uses the cabal-install solver to attempt
    to find some working build configuration. This can be convenient when dealing
    with many complicated constraint errors, but results may be unpredictable.


Plan construction failed.
```

I tried running `stack solver`, but that threw the exception documented [here](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3453).

How can I declare hdevtools as a dependency of my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@alexis-king recommends using `stack build --copy-compiler-tool hdevtools` in [this guide](https://lexi-lambda.github.io/blog/2018/02/10/an-opinionated-guide-to-haskell-in-2018/), in the section titled **Setting up editor integration**.

This works for the current project, and other projects using the same GHC version, but you will need to run it again when you upgrade to a new GHC version.

More context from King's guide:

> As mentioned above, stack install is not what you want. Tools like ghc-mod, hlint, hoogle, weeder, and intero work best when installed as part of the sandbox, not globally, since that ensures they will match the current GHC version your project is using.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I declare hdevtools as a dependency of my project?

`hdevtool` is an executable and cabal doesn't have a concept of development dependencies (like in other package managers like npm etc).  So, all you can do is install `hdevtools` globally and make it work.